# Ferris Wheel Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a CSS ferris wheel animation. It looks fine but if you pay close attention, you will see that some "steps" will be higher than others at the tallest point (12 oclock position ("step1" in the code)). I have a feeling something is wrong in my math but I don't know what exactly.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc4qu/

HTML

```
<div id="wheel" style="height:600px;width:600px;margin:0;postion:relative;">
    <div class="wheel a fa">step1</div>
    <div class="wheel b fa">step2</div>
    <div class="wheel c fa">step3</div>
    <div class="wheel d fa">step4</div>
    <div class="wheel e fa">step5</div>
    <div class="wheel f fa">step6</div>
    <div class="wheel g fa">step7</div>
    <div class="wheel h fa">step8</div>
    <div class="wheel i fa">step9</div>
    <div class="wheel j fa">step10</div>
    <div class="wheel k fa">step11</div>
    <div class="wheel l fa">step12</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wheel
{
    font-size: 120%;

}

div .a
{
     left:300px;
     top: 0px; 
     position:absolute; 
}
div .b
{

     left:450px;
     top:60px; 
     position:absolute; 
}
div .c
{
     left:560px;
     top:150px; 
     position:absolute; 
}

div .d
{
    top:300px; 
    position:absolute;
    left:600px; 
}
div .e
{
     left:560px;
     top:450px; 
     position:absolute; 
}

div .f
{
     left:450px;
     top:560px; 
     position:absolute; 
}


div .g
{
    top:600px;
     left:300px; 
     position:absolute;  
}


div .h
{
    top:560px;
    left:150px;
     position:absolute;  
}
div .i
{
    top:450px;
    left:40px;
     position:absolute;  
}
div .j
{
    top: 300px; 
    left: 0;
    position:absolute; 
}
div .k
{
    top:150px;
    left:40px;
    position:absolute;  
}
div .l
{
     left:150px;
     top:40px; 
     position:absolute; 
}
.fa{float:left;width}
```

JQUERY

```
    var rotation = 0
setInterval(function() {
    $('#wheel').css({
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(-" + rotation + "deg)",
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(-" + rotation + "deg)",
        "-o-transform": "rotate(-" + rotation + "deg)",
        "-ms-transform": "rotate(-" + rotation + "deg)"
    }); 

        $('.fa').css({
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)",
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)",
        "-o-transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)",
        "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)",
    }); 

 rotation = (rotation + 1) % 361
}, 50)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your step elements are rotated around their center, but are positioned based on the top/left corner. ([*see example*](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Lc4qu/4/))

You need to set the rotation origin be the same point as the one you use for the positioning (*the top/left corner*)

So set

```
transform-origin: top left;
```

for the `.fa` elements

(*with vendor prefixes*)

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top left;
-moz-transform-origin: top left;
-ms-transform-origin: top left;
-o-transform-origin: top left;
transform-origin: top left;
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Lc4qu/7/

---

More importantly, you can achieve the same with just CSS3 (*using animation/keyframes*)

Something like this

for `.fa` elements add

```
animation: cycle 18s linear infinite;
```

for the outer `#wheel` add

```
animation: cycle 18s linear infinite reverse;
```

and the cycle keyframes (*demo contains vendor prefixes as well*)

```
@keyframes cycle{
   0% { 
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Lc4qu/8/

Comment: I think you got to the heart of the issue, but it looks like the starting positions are also a little off. http://jsfiddle.net/Lc4qu/5/embedded/result/

Comment: @apaul34208 you are right.. (*i will leave that to the OP to correct, with whatever method he uses to find the initial positions*)

Comment: Ahhh so it was a mathematical issue but I wasn't really looking there. Thank you very much, Gaby. Learned something new today! Also thank you apaul for that link.

Comment: The CSS3 version is much smoother too. Thanks for the alternative!